# How can I set a variable in viewForHeaderInSection, and then use it in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my table's `viewForHeaderInSection`, I'm setting the variable `_searchTerm`, using the section index like so:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 21)];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.949 green:0.949 blue:0.949 alpha:1];

    _searchTerm = [[[[_matchCenterData  objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];

    return nil;
}
```

For each section, I want to use its respective `_searchTerm` variable in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //load top 3 data
    NSDictionary *currentSectionDictionary = _matchCenterData[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *top3ArrayForSection = currentSectionDictionary[@"Top 3"];
    //... code removed to brevity

    // title of the item
    cell.textLabel.text = _searchTerm;
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working, the cells textLabel is showing up as blank. Is it possible to use a variable from `viewForHeaderInSection` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly answer your question, but you could achieve the result that you want by assigning `cell.textLabel.text` to your data source.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[[[_matchCenterData  objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Top 3"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Search Term"];
```

now, the possible reason that your `cell.textLabel.text` is blank, is that because `cellForRow` method is called first before `viewForHeaderInSection`

Comment: very good point (see 2nd to last paragraph in my answer).  the datasource already *does* contain the section info the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider that anything you use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that varies as a function of `indexPath` as part of your datasource.  Second, don't initialize datasource data `viewForHeader`.  Do so in the same place you initialize the rest of the data (the rest of `_matchCenterData`)

So, if you have:

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *matchCenterData;
```

Then also have...

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *searchTerms;  // notice the plural name
```

Where you have:

```
self.matchCenterData = // whatever
```

Then also have (in pseudo code)...

```
for (each section in self.matchCenterData) {
    [self.searchTerms addObject:the thing you were setting in viewForHeader]
```

Now, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, can behave properly with respect to this additional datasource data...

```
cell.textLabel.text = self.searchTerms[indexPath.section];
```

Incidentally, an better datasource might include the sectional information in the matchCenterData, rather than the slightly hackier "parallel array" idea I've proposed here.

Even more incidentally, notice how I declare a property named "foo", then refer to it as `self.foo`, not `_foo`.  With just a few exceptions, that's a practice you should adopt, too.